# targeting anchor tag external div/page with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

In WordPress admin, I put old-fashioned anchor tags and links in the head and footer to get to the bottom and top of my *extremely long plugins page* rather than scrolling and scrolling and scrolling.

I'd like to put a link in the wpadminbar div to target a div id in the wpbody-content div, using ajax or jquery if possible, so it doesn't have to refresh the page.

I've searched similar posts but don't find any which addresses targeting external divs. any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you need. please check this code, i have added an achor link on bottom of the page

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var topSection = $('body');
 var position = topSection.offset();
 $('.slide').on('click', function(){ 
  $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: position.top}, 700)
 });
  
})
```

```css
body {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
 
}
.common {
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 height: 400px;
 background: #000;
 margin-top: 30px;
}
.slide { 
 font-size:20px; 
 float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="common" ></div>
<div class="common" ></div>
<div class="common" ></div>
<div class="common" ></div>
<a href="#" class="slide">slide</a>
```

Comment: this is what I was looking for:

`
$(function() {
      $("#wp-admin-bar-mstba_3828").click(function() {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: $("#second").offset().top
        }, 'slow');
      });
    });
`

turns out the i was working all within one div, thought I was targeting an external DIV. 

Wonder if I can target #second if it was outside of the div that the #wp-admin-bar-mstba_3828 link is in... would it be that simple?

thanks for your reply